# Show breadcrumb on forum only

Tags: breadcrumbs

I want to show the breadcrumb on the forum only. I am using the advanced forum module. How can I do this in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you try the [Disable Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/disable_breadcrumbs) module.

> Disable breadcrumbs on a per node, per content type, or by path (any path) basis; Omitting the need to write additional code in the theme layer (template.php file etc..) to determine the visibilty of breadcrumbs on specific pages. This can be administered on node edit forms and from the content administration page (node operations) to select/unselect multiple nodes for enabled types.

Answer (score 0):

[This page on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/64067) provides info on customizing the breadcrumbs. I'm sure you could do it with a module, but I think it's probably easier just to look at the examples referenced here and modify your theme template files.